Cannot get another message in Socket Server
When I try To send a message to the server, there's no problem after 1 message, but when I try to send another, it fails.
Beacuse of that, my app is buggy, and I don't want that; no one wants that.
Client:
import socket as soc

# Defining The Variables
HOST = '192.168.0.21'  # DON'T Forget To Change it For your computer's Ip Address.
PORT = 1024
client_socket = soc.socket()
Shutdown_Request = "Request_From_Phone_to_Shutdown"
Restart_Request = "Request_From_Phone_to_Restart"

client_socket.connect((HOST, PORT))


def shutdown_btn(e=None):  # Sending Shutdown Request
    client_socket.sendall(Shutdown_Request.encode('utf-8'))
    client_socket.close()


def restart_btn(e=None):  # Sending Restart Request
    client_socket.sendall(Restart_Request.encode('utf-8'))
    client_socket.close()

Server:
import socket as soc
import os

os.system("cls"); os.system("color e"); os.system("title  Server: WakeMate")
print("   Server is Running... ")

def send_ip_to_client():
    pass
print(" Warning: u may forget the line of 11")

def server_program():
    
    #  getting the hostname.
    host = soc.gethostname()
    port = 1024  # initiate port no above 1024.

    server_socket = soc.socket()  # get instance
    server_socket.bind((host, port))  # bind host address and port together
    server_socket.listen() # configure how many clients the server can listen to simultaneously

    while True:
        conn, address = server_socket.accept()  # accept new connection
        print(f"Connection from: {address}")

        while True:
            data_get = conn.recv(1024)
            if not data_get:
                break
            data_convert = data_get.decode('utf-8')
            # Print The Message.
            print(f"Message from client: {data_convert}")
            if data_convert == 'Request_From_Phone_to_Shutdown':
                print("Line 33 is missing.")
                #os.system("shutdown /s /f /t 0")
            elif data_convert == 'Request_From_Phone_to_Restart':
                print("Line 36 is missing.")
                #os.system("shutdown /r /t 0")

        #conn.close()  # close the connection

if __name__ == '__main__':
    server_program()


I want to send multiple messages like non stopping.

"It failing" is not a problem description. It isn't even English.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Anyway Guys i just Deleted the 'client_socket.close()' lines and it got fixed.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
